# PowerShell Microsoft Teams: Get a Team's "GroupID" & assign it to a variable

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have a simple Powershell script to create a Microsoft team, channels, users, and then to associate the users with the channels.  I'm currently prompting user to enter team name, and then to copy past the GroupID, as I cannot figure out how to get just the group ID.  Is there any way I can just get the "GroupID" so I can assign it to a variable and not force the user to copy-paste?

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
$NewTeamName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Name of new Team'
New-Team -DisplayName $NewTeamName
Get-Team -DisplayName $NewTeamName
$GroupId = Read-Host -Prompt 'Copy and past the GroupID above'
Import-csv createTeamChannels.csv | foreach{New-TeamChannel -GroupId $GroupId -DisplayName $_.cname -MembershipType Private}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the member access operator (`.`) to return only the `GroupId` property value of an existing Team.

```
$GroupId = (Get-Team -DisplayName $NewTeamName).GroupId
```

According to [New-Team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/new-team?view=teams-ps), the `GroupId` is output when a Team is created. So you can store the `New-Team` output in a variable and have access to the property.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
$NewTeamName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Name of new Team'
$NewTeam = New-Team -DisplayName $NewTeamName
$GroupId = $NewTeam.GroupId
```

Comment: Thank you...Getting an error:  Cannot bind argument to parameter 'GroupId' because it is null.  I'm trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: You need to `$NewTeamName` to have an actual display name for a Team.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!